# Unable to Show Totals On Datasheet View

Tags: list, 2013, view, datasheet

I have a SharePoint 2013 installation where a list is being displayed in Data Sheet view.  When you select the option for the view to show totals for specific columns, the totals do not display until you click "Stop editing this list".  We are migrating from WSS 3.0 and currently, the total rows show up when in Data Sheet view.  Is this something that has been deprecated?

Comment: Did you ever find out about this? Is there any way to get totals back on the datasheet view?

Comment: I did not.  After the project went live, the user decided to use a different method in displaying the data.